# Cannot remove word from list

Tags: python

I cannot seem to remove a word from several lists. Articles I have found mention that the error is caused by not having the word in the list, although it's clearly there. My question may be that is it tripping an error because it's one combined word?

Here's what I have tried:

```
spotify_data = {'uri':['spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXcBWIGoYBM5M',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX1lVhptIYRda',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX10zKzsJ2jva',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX4JAvHpjipBk',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX4sWSpwq3LiO',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX4SBhb3fqCJd',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DWXRqgorJj26U',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX4dyzvuaRJ0n',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DXcF6B6QPhFDv',
 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DWXJfnUiYjUKT']}

ID = []
for x in spotify_data['uri']:#matching is the list
    if 'spotify:playlist:' in x:#'Where:' is the string we want to remove
        y = x.split()
        y.remove('spotify:playlist:')
        ID.append(' '.join(y))
```

result:

> `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Expected outcome:

```
['37i9dQZF1DX0XUsuxWHRQd',
 '37i9dQZF1DX1lVhptIYRda',
 '37i9dQZF1DX10zKzsJ2jva'
.
.
.
]
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion, you should never iterate over a list you are mutating.

Comment: @kinshukdua I'd agree on the idea, but I do think he is using the `ID` to store the results, instead of restoring into the same list

Comment: Oh yes you're right, my bad

Comment: Try printing `y`. It's not what you think it is. (This is a good first step in debugging things.) Maybe double check the [docs for `split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove that part, the best way is to use `replace()` as in:

```
x.replace('spotify:playlist:','')
```

Comment: Ah I see, although remove also works at times when I have separated strings in a list. Any idea why it's not working this time?

Comment: @Stackbeans remove generally is useful to remove a specific item from a list, a string is a list of letters, so it can be used to remove a letter or more. However if you want to remove a "string", that would only work if you have a list of strings (e.g. `["one","two","three"]` then you can `x.remove("two")`, and you can't use `replace` in this case since the entry will still exist. I hope this explains it.

Comment: A string is not a list of letters, it's an immutable sequence of characters (i.e. it cannot be changed).

Comment: @martineau you are indeed correct. I was inaccurate in my explanation. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Just trying to fight misinformation. The difference is an important distinction. "ABC".replace("B", "2") returns a *new* string, and does not change the original, whereas `x.remove("two")` doesn't return anything but does change the list `x` in-place.

Comment: `x.removeprefix('spotify:playlist:')` would also work, and wouldn't spend time checking the rest of the string either.

Comment: @CrazyChucky To be fair in this exact scenario something as simple as a string slice, perhaps `x[17:]` would work, but I wasn't sure if I should mention that as I wasn't sure if we will deal with the same string order indefinitely (I would assume so, however). I would definitely agree however that removeprefix is a much faster method, and probably more safe than a slice (Since you avoid losing data if for some reason the pre-fix didnt exist)